# Image clicked button issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

How actually to make sure my button change background image when user click on it?

My code

```
btn1.setImage(UIImage(named:"dialpad1.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
btn1.setImage(UIImage(named:"dialpad2.png"),forState:UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

My background image

dialpad1.png

[image]

dialpad2.png

[image]

My setting

[image]

My screen

[image]

Comment: What is your issue ? It's unclear.

Comment: I want to make button change background image when user clicked.

Comment: In your screenshot I think the image is changed for button 1 right ?

Comment: I already edit my question sir. Actually nothing change at all.

Comment: You need to change your button type to custom

Comment: Also you don't need any code for that, you can do this using file inspector  itself. Did you see the image field there, you can specify the image there. Then change the state config drop down to highlighted and specify the highlighted image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Midhun MP, your answer is most correct. I already follow what you suggested. I change State Config to **Highlighted** and select image in **Highlight Background Image**. No coding at all..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a "Custom" type in your UIButton instead of "System".

You can change it from IB:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Register your button for touchdown

myButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTouchDownAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)

Register your button for touchupinside

myButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTouchUpInsideAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func buttonTouchDownAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
  //set highlighted image
}

func buttonTouchUpInsideAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
  //set unhighlighted image
}
```

Comment: I haven't compiled the code I just typed on my phone it should be working. Let me know if any issue I will compile the code